# How to delete all e-mails from a specific address using sieve-language?

Tags: sieve-language

> Filters / sieve filters. Make a filter to check recipient = your custom domain, choose action delete. Run on existing mails. Delete trash by using „Delete all“.

I tried doing that using the `discard;` from my knowledge but this did not work:

```
require "extlists";

if address :is "from" "my-email@domain.com"

{
 discard; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this ?

```
require ["fileinto","discard"];
if address :is "from" "my-email@domain.com" {
  discard;
  stop;
}
```

Comment: It produced an error because "discard" seems not to be a recognised plugin in ProtonMail. It went through when that was removed, but all along it was a GL from https://checksieve.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple sieve filters running in sequence make sure that the filter which may discard a message runs first. It seems if some action was applied on the mail (like applying a label) the discard command does not take effect afterwards.